# Outputting an arbitrary-long line reversed, using an iterative function

Tags: c, recursion

In "A book on c" 4E, p. 225, while discussing recursion, the authors wrote:

> The next example illustrates a recursive function that manipulates characters. It can easily be rewritten as an equivalent iterative function. We leave this as an exercise.

The function reads a line, which gets output reversed.  Here is the code:

```
void wrt_it(void)
{
    int c;

    if ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        wrt_it();
    putchar(c);
}
```

As I understand, the whole point here is that we have no limit on the line length (other then memory). Because `c` is an automatic variable, new instances of it are made each time `wrt_it` is called. Now, how can this easily be rewritten to be iterative; that is, without using dynamic memory allocation, pointers, or variable-length arrays?

Comment: Iterative doesn't mean without using dynamic memory allocation, pointers or variable-length arrays (which standard C doesn't have).

Comment: of course, but the book has discussed none of these up to this point, and they claim it can be done easily (which, presumably, means without learning anything new).  BTW, variable-length arrays is standard C99.

Comment: @Paul, VLA were introduced in C in 1999.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it can be written iteratively without dynamic memory allocation unless you want to restrict the maximum length of the string.

Also, the recursive version has a limit that you will reach before you run out of memory: the size of the stack. A very long string will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: seems like the authors meant just for a fixed amount of chars. a bit disappointing... and thanks for pointing out about stack overflow.